# Jest Babel TypeScript Class Type Parameters Unexpected Token

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm running into an issue with Jest where it cannot understand Class Type Parameters.

[Example Repo](https://github.com/johnstew/webpack-ts-test)

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIH0F.png)

```
SyntaxError: /Users/john/dev/webpack-test/src/__tests__/utils.test.js: Unexpected token (18:40)

      16 | describe('new Drawer()', () => {
      17 |   it('should add and remove socks', () => {
    > 18 |     const sockDrawer = new Drawer<Sock>();
```

I'm using the class generic example from the TypeScript playground.

[Example Code](https://github.com/johnstew/webpack-ts-test/blob/master/src/utils.ts#L14)

```
export class Drawer<ClothingType> {
  contents: ClothingType[] = [];

  add(object: ClothingType) {
    this.contents.push(object);
  }

  remove() {
    return this.contents.pop();
  }
}

export interface Sock {
  color: string;
}

export interface TShirt {
  size: "s" | "m" | "l";
}
```

Then I have a test that is using it. I'm also calling it from within my React app just to make sure it can compile it there and it does so successfully.

[Test Code](https://github.com/johnstew/webpack-ts-test/blob/master/src/__tests__/utils.test.js#L17)

```
it('should add and remove socks', () => {
  const sockDrawer = new Drawer<Sock>();

  sockDrawer.add({ color: "white" });
  expect(sockDrawer.contents).toEqual([{ color: 'white' }]);
  const mySock = sockDrawer.remove();
  expect(sockDrawer.contents.length).toEqual(0);
});
```

[App Code](https://github.com/johnstew/webpack-ts-test/blob/master/src/App.tsx#L16-L18) that compiles fine.

[Babel Config](https://github.com/johnstew/webpack-ts-test/blob/master/babel.config.json)

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "10.17.0"
            }
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
      ]
    }
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solve for this was adding the configuration below to the `presets` within your Babel configuration.

```json
[
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    {
        "isTSX": true,
        "allExtensions": true,
        "jsxPragma": "react",
        "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true
    }
]
```